# How to remove 307 redirect?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

For some reason my site is doing a 307 redirect. It used to have validation in codeigniter, so that if user was not logged in it would redirect. However I took away this validation so that now any person can access that page. Nonetheless, now a 307 redirection appeared and I can't take it away. The CI_cookie is still called, so I'm guessing that the validation and redirect is still cached somewhere, but I don't know how to remove it, nor find any information on google on how to refresh cache if that's what it is.

Here is the header info:
[image]

Note: the redirection used to happened inside the controller, not on a .htaccess file. I used sessions for the user validation. I'm not posting it because it's no longer on the file, however if you need to see it just let me know and I'll update my question.

Also it would be nice if you could explain me the downvote. I know this question isn't a duplicate because I haven't found it anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really clear from question but I would use a cookie manager extension like this one
[image]

and clear the session cookie, you can find the name of the session cookie in config.php

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'your_session_cookie_name';
```

when you delete the session cookie and refresh the page, CI will (in the background) call session_destroy() method and create a new session, so deleting the session cookie from the client will oblige the server to regenerate a new session.

that being said, if destroying the session doesn't help, we can't really answer without seeing the controller

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the controller code in question...I can only make a guess...if you did indeed remove the redirect from the controller, then it could be cached. Try in a different browser, or refer to your browser's documentation for clearing cookies/cached data.