# Can any one Suggest the 307 redirect issue for website for CodeIgniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I Hosted my Codeigniter application in public_html folder. In public folder we moved folder like application, views,controllers. But Ourwebsite redirected to 307 status code. Could any one suggest how to sovle 307 issue. Please Suggest me how to resolve above Issue.

Comment: see your .htaccess and what is its location

Comment: please have a look at this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403705/how-to-remove-307-redirect